# Symfony 5 User roles

Tags: symfony

Im wondering how do I compare users's roles coming from database with a role I suggest something like

```
{% for user in users %}
  {% if user.something == ' EXEMPLE_role' %} 
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: {% if is_granted('ROLE_MANAGER') == false %}
                  my message 
 {% endif %} its what u need?

Comment: Thanks for the reply , no actually , I just wanted to compare roles from DATABASE with a specific role ;) not trying to get current user roles ; thanks tho

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for this

```
{% if 'ROLE_EXAMPLE' in user.roles %}
{% endif %}
```